# Can anyone recommend a good PHP ORM with compatibility for MongoDB?

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm looking for a good PHP ORM framework for MongoDB. I haven't stumbled onto anything that I was really thrilled about yet. Perhaps someone could point me at a few packages that I haven't seen yet. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Which packages did you look at and why did they not thrill you? If you don't include that information, it's likely that you'll get responses like "I like package Y! It does Q and Z." and then you have to respond "that's one of the ones I looked at and I don't like it." That kind of exchange tends to be both inefficient and demoralizing.

Comment: Check out [Doctrine](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/index.html)

Comment: Big +1 for @octern's comment. Don't tell us "I've already discarded some options" without telling us what they are, and why you didn't like them.

Comment: I've looked at Lithium a few months ago (http://lithify.me/) - it was a bit too poorly document (at least at the time), and seemed to be more than what I needed, as it was a whole framework. Most other frameworks seemed to have mongo as an "experimental/beta" feature at the time, as well. Mostly I am looking for something simpler, that is just a pure ORM... so Mondango may be a good fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a list of all officially sanctioned MongoDB Adapters: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/PHP+Libraries,+Frameworks,+and+Tools

Your question is very general. If you have experience with traditional ORM frameworks like Doctrine or Propel, then you should use Doctrine's experimental MongoDB support. If you are just looking for a simple interface then you should look at something like Mandango.

Comment: I'm gonna explore out Mondango, thanks...

Comment: Mandango has better performance (minimum 3x) than doctrine ODM